# Only showing one line

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is my code it is supposed to calculate for each line in my code but it is only producing one line for `MU_w_o_No_Work`.

```
var query2 = from rg in db.MU_Reports.GroupBy(r => new { r.Date, r.Shift, r.Machine_Number })
             join dt in db.Downtime_Reports
             on new { rg.Key.Date, rg.Key.Shift, rg.Key.Machine_Number }
             equals new { dt.Date, dt.Shift, dt.Machine_Number }
             into dtGroup
             select new
             {
                 rg.Key.Date,
                 rg.Key.Shift,
                 rg.Key.Machine_Number,
                 MU = rg.Sum(r => r.MU),
                 NWTotal = dtGroup.Where(dt => dt.Downtime_Code == "9185").Sum(dt => dt.Total_DownTime)
             };

query2.ToList();

foreach (var item2 in query2)
{
    var y = new MU_By_Machine();

    y.Date = item2.Date;
    y.Shift = item2.Shift;
    y.Machine_Number = item2.Machine_Number;
    y.MU = item2.MU;
    y.MU_w_o_No_Work = (item2.MU * 8) / (8 - item2.NWTotal);

    db.MU_By_Machines.Add(y);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

So I don't know what exactly I am doing wrong but here is a sample output:

Sample Input Data

```
Date      | Machine Num. | Shift | MU | DT Hours
7/11/2016 |     1        |   1   | 70 |  2
7/11/2016 |     2        |   2   | 80 |  1
7/11/2016 |     1        |   2   | 60 |  4
7/12/2016 |     2        |   2   | 75 |  1
7/12/2016 |     1        |   2   | 75 |  0
```

Sample Output Data

```
Date      | Machine Num. | Shift | MU | MU w/o No work
7/11/2016 |     1        |   1   | 70 |  93.33 
7/11/2016 |     2        |   2   | 80 |  91.43
7/11/2016 |     1        |   2   | 60 |  120
7/12/2016 |     2        |   2   | 75 |  85.7
7/12/2016 |     1        |   2   | 75 |  75
```

Comment: Are you saying that it's only inserting one `MU_By_Machine` instead of one for each result from `query2`?

Comment: What does `only producing one line for MU_w_o_No_Work` mean? What are you expecting here? It seems that this is just a number so there would be 1 value (its not a complex object).

Comment: It is supposed to do it for multiple lines in my data table but it is only doing it for the last one

Comment: You are not following any of the C# coding conventions, thus my downvote. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx

Comment: Still not following your logic there. You are using `NWTotal` and you have a filter on the generation of this one value (`where` clause) and then you sum the `Total_DownTime` value. So here you have one value per record. You then use that in another loop, again one value per record. You are not making much sense (to me anyways). Maybe it would be better to provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Krythic what convention am I not following to ruffle your feathers

Comment: @JCM MU_w_o_No_Work Is not the desired way to write a variable name.

Comment: @Krythic It was the desired name my boss wanted on the table and since I'm adding it directly into there that is what I put on the code.

Comment: @Igor I have edited my question to include Sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the error:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Its because your connection is actively reading in the `foreach` iteration. You can materialize the list before or in the `foreach` statement using `.ToList()` and then use the `SaveChanges` inside the loop.

```
// this returns a list and does not convert the existing object to a list
// query2.ToList(); 
foreach (var item2 in query2.ToList()) // use ToList here
```

OR

```
// assign the results to a new object
var resultFromQuery2 = query2.ToList(); 
foreach (var item2 in resultFromQuery2)
```

One comment though, it is generally advisable to save changes all at once (outside the loop in this case) instead of in the loop. Especially when dealing with a large number of iterations this will save you considerable overhead and speed up the process. Alternatively you can use some type of batching counter to save every XXX iterations using the % operator (mod).

*disclaimer: I have not looked at your other code like your query itself, just the immediate problem you stated*

Comment: This also only produces 1 result in `MU_w_o_No Work`

Answer (score 0):

I understood what I did wrong in my `foreach` statement i have to add an `if` statement for when `item2.NWTotal` is zero because it cannot assumed that it is zero if there is no value there so here is what my `foreach` statement should look like:

```
foreach (var item2 in query2)
{
   var y = new MU_By_Machine();

   y.Date = item2.Date;
   y.Shift = item2.Shift;
   y.Machine_Number = item2.Machine_Number;
   y.MU = item2.MU;
   if (item2.NWTotal > 0)
       y.MU_w_o_No_Work = (item2.MU * 8) / (8 - item2.NWTotal);
   else
       y.MU_w_o_No_Work = item2.MU;

   db.MU_By_Machines.Add(y);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```